# How to return indented XML using Spring mvc:annotation-driven and ResponseBody

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I've implemented a simple controller that returns a converted XML object using JAXB and @ResponseBody annotation.

My problem is I'm having a hard time to configure the default converter created by mvc:annotation-driven, and I needed to configure it to render my XML indented. I know I can declare my view resolvers, but I wanted to keep using annotation-driven.

I've searched and found that I could configure mvc:annotation-driven through the usage of mvc:message-converters, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding good documentation to configure Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
      <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller"></property>
      <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller"></property>
    </bean> 
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="contextPaths">
     <list>
       <value>put your xml classes path here</value>
     </list>
   </property>
   <property name="marshallerProperties">
       <map>
            <entry key="jaxb.formatted.output">
                <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="jaxb.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
       </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```